# String immutability. Do I have to reassign it to the same variable after changing it?

Tags: java

Strings are immutable, does it mean that i always have to do something like that with a string passed to a method?

```
str= str.toLowerCase();
```

or is

```
str.toLowerCase();
```

fine? I tried the second one and it doesn't give me any errors, why?

Comment: Why did you not just *try* it?

Comment: "Immutable". That means you can't change it.

Comment: I tried it and didn't get a compiler error, hence the question.
i wasn't sure whether java was doing some behind the scenes magic and reassigning new string to str variable for me, so started to wonder whether the first version was really necessary.
It's an honest question, no need to down vote it.

Comment: Consider updating the question to reflect, what I would consider, the real question, which is hiding in your last comment: "Why is there no compiler error when ....?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> String are immutable

Yes, by your own admission. An immutable *object* is one that does not allow its state to be changed. This includes `String` objects.

Then:

```
str.toLowerCase();
```

Creates a *new string* of lower-case characters and *does not use the result*. This is likely a "bug" in this case as `str` still evaluates to the original string object (which was *not* changed because it is immutable).

**There is no compiler error because Java has no way of knowing that the return value was "supposed to be used".** There are times when a method is called for side-effects, even if it also returns a value*. This could be judged to be an error in some pure languages (those without side-effects), but it is not possible in a language with side-effects in general. Some static analysis tools -- not javac, which is just a compiler with a primitive set of warnings -- are capable of detecting such bugs as the above by applying additional heuristic rules.

Ditto, but assigns the *new string* to the *same variable*: (Variables are *not* values/objects.)

```
str = str.toLowerCase();
```

However, there is *no requirement* that the same variable is re-assigned to. Consider the following examples, which may be entirely valid in context:

```
String normalizedTitle = title.toLowerCase();
foo.setTitle(normalizedTitle);
// or, skip normalizedTitle, etc.
foo.setTitle(title.toLowerCase());
```

Happy coding.

---

*An example of relatively common method that causes a side-effect *and* returns a value that is normally ignored is [`List.remove(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29).

Answer (score 6):

Only the first will work; the `String.toLowerCase()` returns is a new string, it doesn't change anything in place.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign:

```
str = str.toLowerCase();
```

These methods return a *new* String - they don't *modify* the String.

Answer (score 1):

A Java String is immutable, so

```
str.toLowerCase();
```

won't change anything in `str` but just return a new String with all characters of `str` converted to lower case. So if you want to use the lower case string of `str` you must code

```
String lower = str.toLowerCase(); 
System.out.println(str + " to lower case: " + lower);
```

If `str` is a method parameter rather than a local variable or field you should not use the following assignment even though it's valid:

```
public String toLowerCase(String str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  return str;
}
```

This is considered a bad programming practice. Never assign a new value to a method parameter (there is enough memory on the call stack ;-).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the first version

```
str = str.toLowerCase(); // the right way
```

since it replaces the reference to the old `String` instance with a reference to the new all lowercase instance. The second version

```
str.toLowerCase(); // the wrong way
```

does not change the `String` instance referred to by `str` (which is what *immutability* means), but returns a new all lowercase instance which is then ignored.

Answer (score 0):

First one. Re-assign it.

```
str= str.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.toLowerCase();` on it's own wont do anything. The method returns a values so you should use that value in an assignment or condition.